# Update a record in the table on Azure mobile backend by TableController

Tags: c#, azure, controller, updates

I created WorkTableController.cs which is inherited from TableController (for using Offline Sync of Azure).

```
   // PATCH tables/Work/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Work> PatchWork(string id, Delta<Work> patch)
    {
         return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/Work
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostWork(Work item)
    {
        WorkOrder current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

I also created AppServiceAccess.cs to invoke api from WorkTableController.cs

```
.....
client = new RestClient(appServiceUrl);
client.AddDefaultHeader("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(result.AccessToken);

public static IRestResponse SendPostRequest(string url, object bodyParameter)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(bodyParameter);
    return client.Execute(request);
}

public static IRestResponse SendPatchRequest(string url, object bodyParameter)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.PATCH);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(bodyParameter);
    return client.Execute(request);
}
```

I can insert data to table Work in database by invoke SendPostRequest(), no problem. But I cannot update any record in table Work by invoke SendPatchRequest().

Could you give me a solution? Where is the problem in my code?
How to update a record in the table on Azure mobile backend by using TableController?

Answer (score 2):

The update operation request would look like as follows:

```
PATCH https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}/{id}
Body: json payload
```

Based on your code, the code would look like as follows:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net");
client.AddDefaultHeader("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
var request = new RestRequest("tables/Work/81c0ca73-e554-4166-a016-c80591bf5924", Method.PATCH);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new
{
    text="hello world"
});
var result= client.Execute(request);
```

For your `SendPatchRequest` method, the parameter `url` need to look like this:

```
tables/{table-name}/{record-Id}
```

**UPDATE:**

You could set `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always` under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` of your mobile app back-end for retrieving detailed error messages to troubleshoot this issue. I just used postman to simulate the patch operation as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to update a field of a record from table Work.
When call SendPatchRequest, I set url = tables/Work/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
But method Patch response: Bad request. Do you know how to generate Delta<Work> ? I think it is problem. Patch method cannot call correctly.

Comment: You could set `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always` under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` of your mobile app back-end for retrieving detailed error messages to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Do you need further assistance?